# Flutter Daemon Fail

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

when i start running vscode. This warning shows up "The Flutter Daemon failed to start". I could not select any device even i could not see any device. I checked previous topics about this problem. but i could not fix it. I will be grateful if you could help me.

[image]

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4517 and https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3680. Possibly due to corrupted Dart installation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.
For my case, git had something to do with this, but I couldn't get any further info.
Deleting and reinstalling DartSDK and Flutter SDK worked for me.
Good luck for you.